# How to rename termset name in 1033 only

Tags: powershell, term-store, term-set

how could i only rename a termset.name in 1033?

```
foreach($TermSet in $TermStoreGroup.TermSets)
{
$TermSetNamee="Hej"
    if($TermSet.Name -eq $TermSetNamee)
    {
    $TermSet.Name="Hello"   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
  $TermSet.Name(“Hello”, 1033)
```